# How to redirect back to stdout after using dup2(..) , and using execvp(...)

Tags: c, exec, stdout, std

I am running multiple commands using execvp().  After using dup2() before one of my execs() it redirects to the file in dup2() as expected.  However, the problem is that any execvp() out after dup2 keeps getting redirected back to the file.  My question is: How can i redirect the out back to the stdout with dup2?

Comment: Are you sure that you call each `execvp` in a separately `fork`-ed process? By not doing so, the first call to `execvp` replaces the image of the process and any consequent instructions (including other calls to `execve`) are not reached at all.

Comment: yes i am using exec, and dup2 in the child process.  if(pidid == 0){....}

Comment: I figured it out.. i had a global variable boolean that i never changed back in the child process once exec finished. dumb mistake

Comment: Unfortunately it is not always amusing to find out a CS20 level programming mistake is appearing to be a CS150 level problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can save stdout with dup() and dup2() it back.

I suggest rather that you do the dup2() to redirect after the fork() (inside the child process) rather than before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a copy of `stdout` before using `dup2`:

```
int stdoutCopy = dup(1);                // Clone stdout to a new descriptor
if(dup2(file, 1) < 0) return 1;         // Change stdout to file
close(file);                            // stdout is still valid

// Do something...
 
if(dup2(stdoutCopy,1) < 0) return 1;    // Change stdout back from the clone
close(stdoutCopy);                      // Close the clone

// Do something...
```